# how to change the slice color in donut chart on click of slice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

can we change the slice color of donut chart when user click .I want to grey out all slice except selected one ..can we grey out all slices when user 
click /select any slice ..
In other words

I have four colors blue ,black , green, orange ..When I click on blue it show blue rest are grey ..when I clcik on black it show black rest are grey .here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/nyhmdtb8/5/

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'pie'
    },

    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {

      symbolHeight: 1,
      symbolWidth: 1,
      symbolRadius: 0,
      useHTML: true,
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      itemWidth: 100,
      layout: 'vertical',
      x: 0,
      y: 100,
      labelFormatter: function() {

        return '<div style="padding:5px;width:55px;background-color:' + this.color + '"><span style="color: #ffffff;">' + this.name + ': <b>' + this.y + '</b> </span></div> </n>';
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Total percent market share'
      }
    },
            plotOptions: {
          pie: {

                  showInLegend: true,
                         dataLabels: {
                        format: '<b>{point.y}</b>',

                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    },
            point: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function (e) {
                    return false;
                  },
                  click:function(e){
                  console.log(this.points)
                   console.log(e);
                    this.graphic.attr({
                fill: 'yellow'
            });
                  //return false;
                  }
                }
              },
                   startAngle: 0,
                  endAngle: 270,
            }
            },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
      shadow: false
    },
    series: [{
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      showInLegend: false,
      name: 'election result',
      enabled: true,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      data: [
        ['A', 55],
        ['B', 65],

      ],
      size: '30%',
      innerSize: '70%',
    }, {
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      name: 'Versions',
      data: [
        ['sdsd', 55],
        ['sdf', 65],
        ['sdf', 65],
        ['sdf', 132],

      ],
      size: '70%',
      innerSize: '80%',

    }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through the series and through the points and change its color with the [Point.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Point.update). If you use `point.graphic.attr(fill: 'grey')`, then the svg elements and js objects will not be in sync.

On load events, preserve the original color for the slices:

```
chart: {
  type: 'pie',
  events: {
    load: function () {
      this.series.forEach(series => {
        series.points.forEach(point => {
          point.options.origColor = point.color;
        });
      });
    }
  }
},
```

On click, change the color according to the clicked point.

```
click: function(e) {
          console.log(this)
          console.log(e);

          this.series.chart.series.forEach(series => {
            series.points.forEach(point => {
              point.update({
                color: this !== point ? 'grey' : point.options.origColor
              }, false, false);
            });
          })
          this.series.chart.redraw();
        }
```

And the last one, modify the legend formatter, if you want its color to be not changed

```
 labelFormatter: function() {

    return '<div style="padding:5px;width:55px;background-color:' + (this.options.origColor || this.color) + '"><span style="color: #ffffff;">' + this.name + ': <b>' + this.y + '</b> </span></div> </n>';
  }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/zwawuem9/

example with changing legend's color: http://jsfiddle.net/zwawuem9/1/

Comment: hey could you please answer of this Question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633642/why-mouse-out-event-not-fire-as-suggested-in-one-stackoverflow-forum

Comment: do you know any thing regarding this Question